# Web caching to reduce bandwidth on low speed connections

Tags: proxy, squid, cache

On my company we have an ISA Server proxy we use to access internet, this server is managed by external administrators and we do not have access to modify its configurations. Lately we have been researching about how we can improve our connection speed caching as much as possible web pages, assets and media in general, -we are not satisfied with the current cache control of ISA Server-. Squid, polipo, Apache traffic server, came up immediately and while we were evaluating them we noticed that none of them can be used to pass-through NTLM authentication to the parent (ISA server) at least on linux. My questions are:

1- Is there any way to achieve ntlm pass-through to the parent ISA Server using Squid, polipo, ATF on windows or linux?

2- Can you provide any recommendations of a free web caching server which can do ntlm pass-through to the parent ISA Server for Win32 or Linux?

3- Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Squid in a transparent fashion ahead of ISA. You wouldn't need to make any changes to your authentication infrastructure and you'd still get the benefit of Squid's caching.

Comment: I wish i could do that, but I can't, thanks anyways!.

Comment: @CarlosCastellanos - What's the requirement that prevents you from doing that? You wouldn't be losing your authentication and you'd get better control of caching.

Comment: Correct me If I'm wrong: To achieve this I have to install squid somewhere between the ISA server and the gateway (router) right?, I do not have access to that subnet, the ISA server hardware is on another office where I do not have access. If I'm wrong please send a link where I can read more

Comment: You are correct. I didn't interpret your lack of control of the ISA Server computer to mean that you didn't have the ability to place something ahead of it in the network.